# My query is missing a row that has a zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I searched for an answer to this but didn't find one for this specific problem.  I am making a database for storing classes created by a teacher, and a lookup table for students enrolled in each class.  I want to run a query that shows each teacher's class and the number of students.  As you can see in the data below, the teacher has two classes with zero students, but only one of them is returning in the query.

The query:

```
SELECT `c`.`ClassID` AS `id`,
  `c`.`Class_Name` AS `name`,
  `c`.`Class_Code` AS `code`,
  COUNT(`e`.`EnrollID`) AS `count`

FROM `CMP_Classes` `c`

LEFT OUTER JOIN `CMP_Student_Enrollment` `e`
  ON `c`.`ClassID` = `e`.`Enroll_ClassID`
  AND `Class_Teacher` = 1

GROUP BY `e`.`EnrollID`
```

The data:

CMP_Classes Table:

```
ClassID | Class_Name                  | Class_Code | Class_Teacher
1       | Mr. Jones' 1st Period Class | QYTNPCGK   | 1
2       | Mr. Jones' 2nd Period Class | HZWNDZPM   | 1
3       | Pizza                       | RRCXQNNE   | 9
4       | Mr. Jones' 3rd Period Class | NFLBXFEQ   | 1
```

CMP_Student_Enrollment Table:

```
EnrollID | Enroll_Student | Enroll_ClassID
3        | 2              | 1
```

Query results:

```
id | name                        | code     | count
2  | Mr. Jones' 2nd Period Class | HZWNDZPM | 0
1  | Mr. Jones' 1st Period Class | QYTNPCGK | 1
```

So, as you can see, there is no row for "Mr. Jones' 3rd Period Class" but there should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by` the unaggregated columns in the `select`:

```
SELECT c.ClassID AS id, c.Class_Name AS name, c.Class_Code AS code,
       COUNT(e.EnrollID) AS `count`
FROM CMP_Classes c LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CMP_Student_Enrollment e
     ON c.ClassID = e.Enroll_ClassID
WHERE c.Class_Teacher = 1
GROUP BY c.ClassID, c.Class_Name, c.Class_Code;
```

All the backticks in your query make it harder to read and write.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I need those backticks for PHP...  I'll try your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it!  I did have to remove the "AS id," etc., from the GROUP BY line, but it worked.